# Iron Router shows my Not Found template before loading with WaitOn: Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I put my subscribe inside a WaitOn function in a controller with Iron Router / Meteor, and while the subscribe is populating the browser shows my notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'.

How to get around this? I thought WaitOn would actually, you know... wait?

My path is dependant on the subscribe containing the URL. i.e.

www.myapp.com/Fred

```
this.route('userShow', {
    path: '/:owner_name', 
    controller: 'UserShowController'
});
```

Comment: Can you please post the content of the `waitOn` function?

Comment: Could you possibly have defined a loadingTemplate which points to your notfoundtempate?

Comment: No sir, I am NOT using a loadingTemplate, should I be?

Answer (score 0):

waitOn *should* actually wait, if the controller is written correctly.

Things to check:

- Are you publishing the collection on the server?
- Did you pass the data correctly to the template? Your data function in the `UserShowController` should look something like `data: function () {return People.findOne({name: this.params.owner_name});},`
- Are you navigating your browser to a valid `:owner_name`?

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, to all your questions, except I use Handlebars helper to return results of find(). The not found template only shows for a few seconds before the correct data is loaded into the page. I'm wondering if I need to use a loadingTemplate ???

Comment: SIDE NOTE: my route is returning the page title, i.e. {title: myUser.username} -- how could I return both the find() and this object {title: myUser.username} ?

Comment: You should use a loading template then. You can use  something like `Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});`

Comment: I'm unclear about your second question. To return the whole cursor of objects just use find and have something like `data: function () {return People.find({name: this.params.owner_name});}`

Comment: Yes, but currently my data: is returning: {title: myUser.username} or NULL if :owner_name is not found. So you to return both {title: myUser.username} & People.find({name: this.params.owner_name}) ? Here title: is what I use to set the page title in browser window.

Comment: I know you've probably moved past this, but for posterity's sake, you would return both your title and cursor in one object: `data: function() { return { title: myUser.username, people: People.find({ name: this.params.owner_name }) }; }`.